# Is there a way to load a page with Cron Job?

Tags: php, database, cron, backup, cpanel

I have created a php file; so every time I run that, it will run copy all the database to a folder inside my host.

So I was wondering is there a way to **call a cron job to load that page every day ?**

Comment: What do you mean "view that page?" What do you want it to do with the viewed page?

Comment: Why have cron load the page? That'd require a full blown HTTP request. cron operates at the filesystem level and could invoke a script directly, without ever involving the web server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, create a shell script say, `myscript.sh`, that calls this php, for example:

```
#!/bin/sh
php yourscript.php
```

and then schedule it in cron to run (for example) every 6 hours:

```
0 */6 * * * ./myscript.sh
```

Comment: I don't work with cPanel, but it looks simple: http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/11_30/CpanelDocs/CronJobs#Adding a cron job

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can.

Do a sudo crontab -e and you can add this line:

```
0 0 * * * /path/to/php /path/to/php/file.php
```

Basically what this means is that everyday at midnight, it will run the command by invoking the php interpreter, and then running your php file.

Make sure your php file has the correct permissions for root (or for whatever user you'd like to run the cronjob under).

Edit: If you're using cPanel, check out this documentation: [http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/11_30/CpanelDocs/CronJobs#Adding a cron job](http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/11_30/CpanelDocs/CronJobs#Adding%20a%20cron%20job)

Comment: do i need to add 'sudo crontab ' in cPanel ?

Comment: Hmm, not sure how you'd do it in cPanel. These instructions are for directly using Linux/Unix terminal. The command `sudo crontab -e` simply opens up the cronjob listings and allows you to add a line.

Comment: Just find the tab/page for cron jobs, it will have some interface for how often you want it to run, then specify the path.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean by 'view'.  You can certainly set up a cron job that runs PHP cURL, or shell commands (wget, curl, etc.), but it won't be loaded in a browser.